# Size of a Propel On Demand Collection

Tags: php, collections, propel

I use OnDemandCollection with Propel, by calling

```
->setFormatter(ModelCriteria::FORMAT_ON_DEMAND)
```

to my query.

This is great as it can treat as many results as needed (up to 200 000 tested). However I need to get the number of results.

The resulting Propel Collection has a size of -1 (probably because each row is loaded on demand), so I tried

```
count($collection)
$collection->count()
$ite_cloned = clone $collection->getIterator()
iterator_count($ite_cloned)
```

But none returned me the count.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use `count` on this collection as it's on-demand and it would be incredible slow. Better is to use your query object and fire `->count()` on it.

Comment: In this case the query will be executed twice, I d like to avoid this as this is a huge query

Comment: of course, but it's faster than receiving all items and check it at PHP's side.